# Why does Visual Studio Code not have intellisense for Unity keywords such as transform, or Vector3?

Tags: c#, macos, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am trying to learn `Unity3d` game development and would really appreciate some help here...

My issue is that upon typing a word such as `transform` (e.g transform.Rotate), instead of Intellisense lighting it up as a keyword, it highlights other suggestions such as `OnTransformChildrenChanged()`
or `OnTransformParentChanged()`.

Any possible way of fixing this?

I just downloaded Visual Studio Code and the extensions needed to work with Unity3d.

I also have Unity3d's code editor set to Visual Studio Code via `Preferences -> External Tools -> External Tool Editor`.

I have watched multiple tutorials and downloaded multiple extensions for unity tools in VSCode, but still no fix to the Intellisense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first download and install this runtime app
Windows: .NET Framework 4.6 Targeting Pack
macOS: Download .NET SDK.
download link all package for unity ([package](https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/unity-5.5.0)).

Open up Unity Preferences>-> External Tools>-> as External Script Editor.

after this choice the browse for the Visual Studio Cod executable .

The Visual Studio Code executable can be found at mac (osx) 
/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app.
or at  windows
C:\users{username}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe 
 by default.
after restart both application 
double click on c# file and choice VS code for ide.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? I don't know what .NET SDK download is and I can't seem to find it in the link you provided. I am on macOS and I downloaded Unity via Unity Hub if it helps. sorry

Comment: download this version .    https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/thank-you/dotnet-sdk-2.2.107-macos-x64-installer      ----- and check in terminal  with this code ( dotnet --version )

Answer (score 2):

I realize what my problem was, it had to do with **HOW** I was opening my C# scripts.

In Unity, instead of double clicking the C# script to open it up in VSCode, Right click the `Assets Folder` and then choose `Open C# Script`.

This solved the problem I was having completely.